# How do I get a integer to keep dividing itself?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have tried everything, and I am stuck. Any help would be helpful :) I need the output to be from 10.0, 5.0, 2.5, 1.25, 0.625 My problem is I can't get the program to stop at 0.625.

```
'user_num = 20'
while user_num  > 10:
    user_num = user_num/2.0
print(user_num)
```

Comment: Is the posted code what you are actually running? If not, please correct (e.g. the first line and the indentation of the print statement).

Comment: Thank you @jarmod  yes it did run, just infinitly. Someone below just answered for me which I spent almost all night on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about simply changing you inequality criterion?

```
user_num = 20
while user_num > 0.625:
    user_num /= 2.0  # equivalent to doing user_num = user_num/2.0
    print(user_num)
```

Which prints

```
10.0
5.0
2.5
1.25
0.625
```

---

Comment: @Lauren If so, would you be okay with ticking my answer as correct? ;)

Comment: Absolutely! go ahead, I'd do it for you but it won't let me =(

Comment: if you wouldn't mind helping me with another one, I'd appreciate it. For some reason it's not giving me any output

Comment: @Lauren Which one ?

Comment: The activity calls for the integer output to multiply by itself, 8 16, 32, 64   
       num_insects = 8 # Must be >= 1

        while num_insects <= 8:
                   print(num_insects * 2)
         if num_insects == 64:
            break

Comment: @Lauren What about: `while num<64:num *= 2;print(num)` ?